# Excel copy of a query cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In my spreadsheet, cell B1 displays the result of a query. Such query (which is designed to always return 1 row, 1 column) contains one '?' parameter, which I associated to the value of A1 cell. A1 value depends on the values of several columns in the same row. Everything works fine.

Now, I want to copy the entire row to row 2, and I would like cell B2 to automatically associate its '?' parameter to the value of A2. Instead, what I get is that the query in B2 is still run with the value of A1.
Changing the reference from $A$1 to A1 in the query parameter properties before copying does not change this behavior.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ? represent one Character

Comment: the '?' character is what Excel uses to represent a parameter passed to a query